# What is wrong with this php RSS feed?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, rss

This is the code I am using:

```
<?php
include "global.php";

$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `approved`='1' ORDER BY time DESC";
$res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$xml_output = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";
$xml_output .= "<rss version=\"2.0\">\n\n";
$xml_output .= "<channel>\n\n";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $content = ShortenText($row['content'], 500);

    $xml_output .= "\t<item>\n";
    $xml_output .= "\t\t<title>" . $title . "</title>\n";
        $content = str_replace("&", "&", $content);
        $content = str_replace("<", "<", $content);
        $content = str_replace(">", "&gt;", $content);
        $content = str_replace("\"", "&quot;", $content);
    $xml_output .= "\t\t<description>" . $content . "</description>\n";
    $xml_output .= "\t\t<link>" . "http://projectstratos.com/post.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "</link>\n";
    $xml_output .= "\t</item>\n";
}

$xml_output .= "</channel>\n\n"; 
$xml_output .= "</rss>";

echo $xml_output;
?>
```

And it shows a blank rss feed page, why is this?

Comment: Maybe it just looks like the page is blank, have you checked the source ?

Comment: Wouldn't you be better of using  "<![CDATA[" and  "]]>" aroudn your content?

Comment: It also lacks the Content-Type: header output, which many RSS readers grouch about.

Comment: @mailo yes it just looks blank every thing is there in the source, why is this? @Nanne do you mean instead of the <?php tags? @mario could you give an example?

Comment: Yes! using the <![CDATA[ tags worked! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you aren't correctly escaping the XML here:

```
$content = str_replace("&", "&", $content);
$content = str_replace("<", "<", $content);
```

These two lines aren't actually doing anything. You are just replacing a string with the same string. Did you mean `&amp;` instead of `&` and `&lt;` instead of `<` for the replacement strings?

A better way is to use CDATA tags but this still won't escape all characters correctly.

Even better still - use the [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) classes to generate the XML for you rather than escaping it yourself.

Comment: The real question is, why isn't he just using `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: @mario because `htmlspecialchars` isn't XML-safe.